# USB devices do not work after suspend

Tags: linux, usb, pop-os, hp

I have an HP omen 15 laptop, using Pop OS 20.04 (kernel 5.13.0-7620-generic).
Whenever I wake the laptop after suspend, my connected usb devices stop working. Following others' advice, I set the kernel option using kernelstub:

```
usbcore.autosuspend=-1
```

However this doesn't seem to affect anything. I tried another suggestion using `usbreset` from `usbutils`.
This is the result before suspending:

```
stan@pop-os:~$ usbreset
Usage:
  usbreset PPPP:VVVV - reset by product and vendor id
  usbreset BBB/DDD   - reset by bus and device number
  usbreset "Product" - reset by product name

Devices:
  Number 003/002  ID 046d:c52b  USB Receiver
  Number 001/002  ID 30c9:000e  HP Wide Vision HD Camera
  Number 001/003  ID 8087:0029
```

And this is after suspend and wake:

```
stan@pop-os:~$ usbreset
Usage:
  usbreset PPPP:VVVV - reset by product and vendor id
  usbreset BBB/DDD   - reset by bus and device number
  usbreset "Product" - reset by product name

Devices:
```

So no devices detected there.

EDIT: turns out that some devices are not affected, like external hdd. But any kind of mouse/keyboard is affected, doesn't matter if it is wireless or not. Strangely enough, the integrated camera also stops working.

Everything works fine on reboot.

Comment: I have this same issue. It started a few weeks ago after I did a fresh install and I've been hoping some random apt update would fix it. I'm on 21.04 though.

When it happens, I have to reboot and then everything works fine. It might work for a few hours or a few days and it does not necessarily happen after  waking. It will happen to me in the middle of using my machine. I will also throughout the day get random beeps from my machine like I'm unplugging a usb drive and plugging it back in.

Comment: Same issue here on 5.16.2-arch1-1. Tried all the same steps you did and nothing has worked.

Comment: EDIT: tried Pop 21.10 - issue persists. Tried Ubuntu 20.04 with the same kernel - no issues there, so my initial assumptions of kernel bug are incorrect. I see on the Manjaro forums that they experience exactly the same issue with this HP model, so it is not strictly a Pop OS bug...

Comment: lsusb only shows USB root hubs after resume.

5.15.0-47-generic in Ubuntu MATE 22.04.1 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish) on an Acer Aspire 3. CPU is AMD Ryzen 5 3500U and the motherboard has an AMD Raven USB 3.1 controller.

Answer (score 1):

I had this similar issue and sadly I do not think that there is any software change that can be implemented to fix this.

However I recently had to get my laptop fixed (due to one of the keys to stop working) which required a PCB replacement.

Due to HP's weird design choices, I believe the entire USB/keyboard PCB is a single daughter-board. Furthermore, as the keyboard PCB was replaced, so were all the internal USB controllers. The keyboard also came with a windows 11 key instead of windows 10 which compels me to believe this is a more recent model.

It seems that this newer hardware prevents the issues that are present, meaning that it is most likely a hardware bug.

Comment: I also tried a variety of kernel's/OS's before I sent the laptop in for repair and it never worked.. Now works perfectly after replacement.